# Magento Products don't redirect between store views

Tags: magento, locale, redirect, magento-1.9

I have two store views in my Magento installation, `default` with `es_ES` locale and `en_view` with `en_GB` locale.

I would like when I add a product to a category with `All store views` set, system automatically creates redirection between store views.
This way if I'm in `default` store view, visiting a product in a category when I switch to `en_view` Magento must change to category and product in `en_GB`.

An example:

`camisetas/playa.html (default) -> shirts/beach.html (en_view)`

In fact I have a lot of redirects between store views than Magento has automatically created, but I don't know in which moment.

Now, when I add a product to a category none redirections are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add product in site from admin, there are option to display that product in all or specific websites. There is WEBSITE tab in left-side and you can chose all or specific store to display your product.